# A matrix game without a pure strategy equilibrium

Tags: matrices, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I would like to see a matrix $2\times 2$ game **without** a pure strategy Nash equilibrium.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @molarmass I cannot even come up with a bimatrix game without PSNE.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
& H & T \\ 
\hline
H & (1, 0) & (0, 1) \\ \hline
T & (0, 1) & (1, 0) \\ \hline
\end{array}

There is no Nash equilibrium in pure strategies, but there exists a Nash equilibrium in mixed strategies, both players choose H with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and T with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.